# trouble with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, file-io

I need to find a string inside of a file; I copied and pasted the exact string from the file into the pattern spot, but I still can't find it. The `print` commands return empty strings, except for the first name. Here is my code:

```
def fillWindow(self,student):
    global fileDirectory
    location = path.join(fileDirectory, student + '.txt')
    file = open(location, 'r')

    # find item in list and then place it in the text box   
    firstName = re.findall(r'firstName\:', file.read())
    print(firstName)
    self.firstNameBox.insert(0,'firstName')

    lastName = re.findall(r'lastName\:', file.read())
    print(lastName)
    self.lastNameBox.insert(0,'lastName')

    family = re.findall(r'family\:', file.read())
    print(family)
    self.familyNameBox.insert(0,'family')

    file.close()
```

And here are the contents of the file:

```
firstName: test
lastName: one
family: family
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your better bet would be to read the lines of the file in using readlines() or xreadlines().  Something like this:

```
input = open('input')

for line in input.xreadlines():
  if line.startswith('firstName'):
    firstname = line.split()[1]
  elif line.startswith('lastName'):
    lastname = line.split()[1]
  elif line.startswith('family'):
    family = line.split()[1]

input.close()

print firstname
print lastname
print family
```

Also, if you want to use a regular expression for this, you'll want to use something like:

```
import re
line = "family: blah"
m = re.search("family: (.*)", line)
if m != None:
  print m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think file.read() will move the cursor so subsequent calls will attempt to read from the end of the file.

You could read the contents of the file into a variable first, and then perform the regex searches in that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make the file format a tad bit more flexible, you can use the built in Config Parser module (`ConfigParser` in 2.X, `configparser` in 3.x)

For the file:

```
[default]
firstName: test
lastName: one
family: family
```

The following code would work fine:

```
import ConfigParser

def fillWindow(self,student):
    global fileDirectory
    location = path.join(fileDirectory, student + '.txt')
    parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    parser.read(location)
    firstName = parser.get('default','firstName')
    lastName = parser.get('default','lastName')
    family = parser.get('default','family')
```

**EDIT** Alternately, your original file could be parsed with csv as pointed out by eyquem:

```
import csv

def fillWindow(self,student):
    global fileDirectory
    location = path.join(fileDirectory, student + '.txt')
    reader = csv.reader(open(location),delimiter=':')
    dict = {}
    for row in reader:
        dict[row[0]] = row[1]
```

Comment: Because I had never used that before!  Fantastic.

Comment: And I had never seen the configparser module ! And now I know. Terrific !

Answer (score 0):

Mamma mia ! So much complications !

```
def fillWindow(student):
    global fileDirectory
    location = path.join(fileDirectory, student + '.txt')

    pat = re.compile('firstName: (.*)\r?\n'
                     'lastName: (.*)\r?\n'
                     'family: (.*)')

    with open(location, 'r') as f:
        ch = f.read()

        firstName,lastName,family = pat.search(ch).groups()
        # or li = pat.findall(ch) if there are several

        print(firstName)
        self.firstNameBox.insert(0,'firstName')
        print(lastName)
        self.lastNameBox.insert(0,'lastName')
        print(family)
        self.familyNameBox.insert(0,'family')
```

By the way, what is the purpose of the instruction `global fileDirectory` ??

I suppose there are several sections like

```
firstName: test
lastName: one 
family: family
```

so why not use a **csv.reader()** or **csv.DictReader()** ?